# Recommended way to disable atd (and other unnecessary startup processes) in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, init.d, startup, chkconfig

I just spun up a new Ubuntu 14.04 server and have been having a bit of trouble getting the `atd` daemon to stop auto-launching. There's been a bit of changing around on the management of startup processes, and I've viewed dozens of web pages on upstart, sysv-rc-conf, and other start management systems (not to mention chk-config, which isn't available anymore on Ubuntu anyway)…

I tried using sysv-rc-conf, but with the configuration as follows, I still have atd running on reboot:

```
# sysv-rc-conf --list atd 
atd          0:off  1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

Even though it's not upstart-compatible, I put "manual" into `/etc/init/atd.override`

I've also tried a couple of variant invocations of update-rc.d, but despite the promising output, atd still launches on reboot:

```
# update-rc.d atd disable 0123456
update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match atd Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match atd Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
 Disabling system startup links for /etc/init.d/atd ...
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/atd ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K80atd
   /etc/rc1.d/K80atd
   /etc/rc2.d/K80atd
   /etc/rc3.d/K80atd
   /etc/rc4.d/K80atd
   /etc/rc5.d/K80atd
   /etc/rc6.d/K80atd
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/atd ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K80atd -> ../init.d/atd
   /etc/rc1.d/K80atd -> ../init.d/atd
   /etc/rc6.d/K80atd -> ../init.d/atd
   /etc/rc2.d/K80atd -> ../init.d/atd
   /etc/rc3.d/K80atd -> ../init.d/atd
   /etc/rc4.d/K80atd -> ../init.d/atd
   /etc/rc5.d/K80atd -> ../init.d/atd
```

I'd prefer not to just brute-force it and whack the scripts, but after all this, that's what I'm tempted to do. Are there any **recommended** (or just *practical* and *maintainable*) ways to deal with startup issues like this in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like everything works like upstart is supposed to (I had put my files in the wrong directory!):

I just did the following:

```
echo "manual" > /etc/init/atd.override
```

and voila -- the atd process no longer starts up on reboot!